# Pydev does not recognize packages that ipython does

Tags: python, pydev, packaging

I created a package.
It can be "pip installed"

That package is recognized in ipython, can be imported, and even auto-completes.

Same said package is unrecognized in pydev in eclipse on the same computer and does not autocomplete. 
However, when I run the code n pydev, it works fine.

Comment: Is the new package in your path? In your PyDev "path"? (aka imported). I don't use PyDev, but it sounds like it is just not in the path or added to PyDev.

Comment: A python package is not "in a path" it was installed using pip install and can be imported and works fine. the only problem is the the eclipse IDE does not recognize it and shows a red error icon.